# The Dataflow appears to be stuck

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Got the following message: 
`The Dataflow appears to be stuck. Please reach out to the Dataflow team at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-dataflow.`

I realized there were other questions regarding the same error message, but the context seemed different for each and the message rather generic, so I'm posting again.

Job ID: 2017-09-25_09_27_25-5047889078463721675

Please assist. Thanks.

EDIT: Problem seems to have disappeared (at least for now) after updating to Apache Beam SDK for Python 2.1.1 from 2.0.0.

Answer (score 3):

A common cause of stuckness in Dataflow pipelines is an inability to start the workers. If you look at the Stackdriver Logs (view Logs in the UI, and click the link to go to Stackdriver) you should be able to view the `worker_startup` logs. Any problems here can indicate failures to start workers, which would cause the job to be stuck.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem rather seems to be related to containers. In stackdriver, one recurring error message stands out under `kubelet`:

`Error syncing pod <some_pod>, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "python" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 20s restarting failed container=python pod=<some_pod>"`

Comment: That sounds like the worker container failed to startup. If you look at the messages in the `worker_startup` logs it may tell you why the `python` (worker) container failed to start.

Comment: @MeteKemertas Did you manage to figure this one out? It seems that I'm facing the same issue